# Convolutional net topology

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network

I have been implementing a convolutional neural net for Character recognition (MNIST) and I'm having troubles when trying to train it (basically the CNN doesn't learn). So I was wondering if the topology that I used is wrong...

***CNN topology:***

Input -> Conv layer 3*3 (10 filters)  -> Maxpool 2*2 -> Conv layer 4*4 (30 filters) -> Maxpool 2*2 -> Fully Connected layer -> Fully Connected layer -> Fully Connected layer (the result of this layer is the output).

As you see, I'm not using softmax, but I think that not using it should not be the problem.
I also use **root-mean-square error** as **loss function**.
Another thing I want to add is that, when I say that it doesn't learn, I mean that 10% of the time the output is correct, but I noticed that the output that is correct is when the image is a 9 (and not any other number).

If anyone could give me some advice about some CNN structure or about an existing CNN, I would thank you a lot.

Comment: Have you tried using a softmax layer at the end? Also, how many filters are you using in your convolutional layers?

Comment: I'm going to try with softmax, but as I said before, the only thing that should differ is that using softmax the performance should be better. Nevertheless, the CNN should be about 80% accurate without using softmax (what I mean is that the performance should be higher than 10%). //I added the number of filters of each conv layer in the question

Comment: The structure of your CNN should be fine, so I think the problem is probably a bug in your implementation. This could be all sorts of things depending on the frameworks (or lack thereof) that you're using.

Comment: The thing is that I made some tests (some values invented by me) and the CNN learns well, but when trying to learn MNIST, it doesn't. Do you know how many epochs do I have to do to train a CNN (and how much time does it take)? Because when I use a perceptron net, it takes 2 or 3 epochs for 94% accuracy

Comment: In my experience it should produce results much better than random chance after just one epoch, and >90% accuracy after two or three.

Comment: @Malvrok What is the output you're training your ConvNet on? In a typical neural net model on MNIST, the output is a matrix of 10 binary column, thus you need softmax at the top layer.

Comment: Yeah, as you say, I'm using a binary column as output. Nervertheless, using or not softmax, the accuracy should be higher than 10%. I had also implemented a perceptron net, and without using softmax layer, the accuracy is almos 94%.